# Making a custom scrollbar hide and unhide on hover

Tags: scrollbar, mousehover

How can I make a scrollbar for my page that appears when I place my cursor at the corner ?

I found out a way to make the scrollbar appear and disappear on hover by using the following:

```
div { overflow:hidden;height:whatever px; }

div:hover { overflow-y:scroll; }
```

But that only applies to div tags. I want the scroll-bar to appear only when I take my cursor at the right edge of the page. I tried using `body` instead of `div` but then it disturbs all the pages even to those which have less contents.

Please suggest me a way to do so.

Comment: can you please make a jsfiddle?

Comment: okay give me a minute I will make one

Comment: jsfiddle is down. use http://www.jsbin.com

Comment: yes there was a gateway error. trying on jsbin now thanks

Comment: I made a live demo here http://liveweave.com/yo7Afy

Comment: Here is the link. When i take the cursor to the body the scrollbar appears but as soon as i take it to the corner it disappears. What i want is the other way round.
http://jsbin.com/ejerav/10/edit

Comment: What you created is exactly how I want it to happen but will that work on the whole page or only on the box because I don't want the effect to be applied on only one div or box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i have understood is that you want something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Liveweave</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.right').hover(function(){
       $('.box').css('overflow-y','scroll');
      },function(){
        $('.box').css('overflow','hidden');
      });
    });
  </script>


    <style type="text/css">  


.box
{
     overflow:hidden;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: yellow;
     overflow: hidden;
}

.box:hover
{
        /*overflow-y:scroll;*/
}

      .body{width:100%}
      .right{float:right;min-height:50px;position:absolute;right:0}

    </style>

</head>  

<body>
<div class="body">
  <div class="right">
    right edge
  </div>
  <div class="box">asdfsadfsdafsdafsdaf,
   sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd
    sadfsd

    sdf
    sadf
    sdf
    dsf
    sdfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdaf
    sdffsdf</div>






</body>




</html>
```

Comment: What you did was exactly the behavior that i want but I don't want in the box. I want it for the body and I want it only when I hover to the edge of the page.

Comment: change the script part to

<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.right').hover(function(){
       $('body').css('overflow-y','scroll');
      },function(){
        $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
      });
    });
  </script>

Comment: also replace css of .right with 

.right{float:right;min-height:100%;position:absolute;right:0}